# PDO prepared statement with tables

Tags: php

I have two tables "Student" and "Lecturer" in my database but just want to use same login function for the both tables. Can i achieve it using prepared statement like this

```
function login ($username,$password,$table) {
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(id) from :table where username=:username AND password=:password');
$query->bindParam(':table' , $table);
$query->bindParam(':username' , $username);
$query->bindParam(':password' , $password);
  if ($count == "1") {
      return true;
  }else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Table and Column` names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.

Comment: Hmmm!!! thought i could do that. Well thanks